# Building a tree in python

Tags: python, tree

Please can someone confirm if this code is the best way to build the following tree

```
           0
         /   \
        1      1
       / \    / \
      3  8    4  7
```

````
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, right = None, left= None):
        self.value = value
        self.right = right
        self.left = left
    def addNode (self, list_parent_nodes, child_value):
        if self.value >=0:     
            if len(list_parent_nodes) > 1:
                if list_parent_nodes[0] == 0: 
                    self.left.addNode (list_parent_nodes[1:], child_value)
                else:
                    self.right.addNode (list_parent_nodes[1:], child_value)
            else:
                if list_parent_nodes[0] == 0:
                    self.left = Node(child_value)
                else:
                    self.right = Node(child_value)
    def printTree(self,level=0):
        if self.value >=0:
            output = self.value
            print("  "*level + str(output))
            if self.left: self.left.printTree(level+1)
            if self.right: self.right.printTree(level+1)

g = Node(0)
g.addNode ([0], 1)
g.addNode ([1], 1)
"""Graph looks like
   0
  / \
 1   1
 """

g.addNode ([0,0], 3)
g.addNode ([0,1], 8)
g.addNode ([1,0], 4)
g.addNode ([1,1], 7)
"""Graph looks like
           0
         /   \
        1      1
       / \    / \
      3  8    4  7 
"""
g.printTree()

```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Please read over [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as your naming style is unidiomatic, and would cause programmers to be confused when seeing your code in the wild.
- I would move getting and setting a node by index into their own functions.
- `if self.value >= 0` only hinders your code, the value `-1` is perfectly valid in binary trees. It also means that you're limiting `value` to types that can be compared to integers, meaning you can't enter strings.
- Using recursion in `addNode` is a good idea, but I find the non-recursive alternate to be easier to understand.
- Your code doesn't care if I enter `addNode([0, 2], 1)`. This seems fishy as if this were a Trinary Tree that would mean something completely different. I recommend raising a `ValueError` in this case.
- Your `printTree` is pretty good.
- I'd change the `level` argument in `printTree` to be a keyword argument only. This is because then it's explicit that it's changing the level, and it's something normal code shouldn't accidentally change.
- Personally I think `if self.left is not None` is better here than `if self.left`, but as `Node` can't be falsy it doesn't matter too much.
- I've added some basic docstrings, defined in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).
- I have also added some [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to your code.
- By using `typing` and [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) I found that `addNode` can error when the specified path doesn't exist. It would be better in these cases to raise an error telling the user why.
- You can use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to prevent code running on import. This means if you later import this code in another module then the testing code won't run.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Optional, Sequence


class Node:
    """Test binary tree."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            value: Any,
            right: Optional[Node] = None,
            left: Optional[Node] = None,
    ):
        """Initialize binary tree, with specified children nodes."""
        self.value = value
        self.right = right
        self.left = left

    def _get_index(self, index: int) -> Optional[Node]:
        """Get node via integer index."""
        if index == 0:
            return self.left
        elif index == 1:
            return self.right
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid index {index}')

    def _set_index(self, index: int, value: Node) -> None:
        """Set node via integer index."""
        if index == 0:
            self.left = value
        elif index == 1:
            self.right = value
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid index {index}')

    def add_node(self, parents: Sequence[int], value: Node) -> None:
        """Add the provided node to the tree."""
        node: Optional[Node] = self
        for index in parents[:-1]:
            if node is not None:
                node = node._get_index(index)
        if node is None:
            raise ValueError("Parent node doesn't exist.")
        node._set_index(parents[-1], value)

    def add_value(self, parents: Sequence[int], value: Any) -> None:
        """Add the provided value to the tree."""
        self.add_node(parents, Node(value))

    def print_tree(self, *, level: int = 0) -> None:
        """Print the tree."""
        print('  ' * level + str(self.value))
        for child in (self.left, self.right):
            if child is not None:
                child.print_tree(level=level + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = Node(0)
    tree.add_value([0], 1)
    tree.add_value([1], 1)
    r"""
    Graph looks like
       0
      / \
     1   1
     """

    tree.add_value([0, 0], 3)
    tree.add_value([0, 1], 8)
    tree.add_value([1, 0], 4)
    tree.add_value([1, 1], 7)
    r"""
    Graph looks like
               0
             /   \
            1      1
           / \    / \
          3  8    4  7
    """
    tree.print_tree()
```